# Не пушатся изменения в репозиторий git

Tags: linux, windows, git

Я создаю репозиторий git в Linux. И когда пытаюсь записать изменения в этот репозиторий из под Windows, изменения не записываются. Ошибок не выдаёт. Зависает в момент команды `git push origin master`. Иногда когда принудительно отменяешь выгрузку изменений, изменения появляются в репозитории. Как с этим бороться? Как следует настроить репозиторий из под Linux, чтоб в него выгружались изменения из Windows?

Comment: Из вопроса мало что понятно. Где находится линукс? Где находится винда? Где находится репозиторий?

Comment: @Эникейщик Linux находиться на локальном компьютере. Там создаётся общий репозиторий. Локальной сетью связаны все компы в организации. Путь подключения к компу я задаю следующий: git://192.168.1.20/modeling3d/ . В результате из под Linux я могу залить изменения и забрать их. Вот только под Windows я могу только забрать изменения. Залить не получается.

Comment: @Эникейщик Windows находиться тоже на локальных компьютерах организации.

Comment: если можете забрать, то проблема наверняка не в гите, а в каких-нибудь правах доступа

Comment: @Эникейщик А можно подробней описать, как настроить репозиторий в Linux? Чтоб этим репозиторием можно было пользоваться из под Windows?

Comment: *А можно подробней описать, как настроить репозиторий в Linux Чтоб этим репозиторием можно было пользоваться из под Windows?* вообще-то никак: нет ничего «специального». а судя по описанию — проблема на стороне клиента. вы всё-таки покажите хотя бы url хранилища. в случае, когда «работает», и когда ­— «не работает».

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Клонируется репозиторий одинаково что из под Windows, что из под Linux git clone  git://192.168.1.20/modeling3d/  dest . git push по этому url не проходит. реально данные в репозиторий кладутся, но выводиться ошибка что push не прошёл.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, какая именно ошибка? git не может писать "push не прошел" (гэндальф.jpg)

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, [почитайте](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B), обратив особенное внимание на зачем-то выбранный вами git-протокол.